# Google Chrome passwords suddenly disappeared how to fix?

Tags: google-chrome

All my saved passwords suddenly disappeared  from passwords.google.com  how to fix.

Sorry if this is off topic super urgent though.

Comment: You can clear credentials in Chrome. If you did this, then your passwords are gone. Hopefully you have a separate password manager.